# Downgrade pre installed Python version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python3.6 and I've to downgrade it to 3.5 to support few projects.

I’m aware of the fact that, touching installations coming as part of OS will lead to the OS level issues.. Is there any safe way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing multiple python versions could be achieved with  [venv](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#venv) for Python 3

Where `venv` manages virtual environments for a specific Python version.

`$ sudo apt install python3.5`

`python3.5 -m venv env/place/you/want/to/save/to` which will create a sandbox with the desired python version

- venv is available by default in Python 3.3 and later, and installs pip and setuptools into created virtual environments .
- venv module provides support for creating lightweight “virtual environments” with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system site directories. Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (which matches the version of the binary that was used to create this environment) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories.
- `source <VENV_NAME>/bin/activate` to switch into your virtual env <VENV_NAME> and used the desired python version